# Oracle simple Select query optimization

Tags: oracle, select, optimization

I have below simple dynamic select query

```
Select RELATIONSHIP 
  from DIME_MASTER 
 WHERE CIN=? AND SSN=? AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER=?
```

The table has 1,083,701 records. This query takes 11 to 12 secs to execute which is expensive. DIME_MASTER table has ACCOUNT, CARD_NUMBER INDEXES. Please help me to optimize this query so that query execution time is under fraction of second.

Comment: Well put a single index on all 3 of `cin`, `ssn` and `account_number` in order of selectivity (the one with the most unique values in the column should be first). Make the index unique if possible... then the dynamic is scary... I assume you mean you change the variables rather than build the query each time.

Comment: Well, without the proper indexes, no wonder this is slow... What did you try? What does execution plan show?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: When the total number of result list is high, the query will take some time to execute. So ensure whether the given constraint gives so many result or not.

Comment: @Ben The order of the columns in the index doesn't matter if you have equality condition on all of them.  It's O(log n).

Comment: I am trying to use above query from Java code and due to its performance my other part of code is slowing down. I am not DBA therefore when i try to do explain or execution plan from sqldeveloper it gives me error that table or view does not exists.

Comment: Please note: I cannot alter table structure due other applications are dependent on it therefore i have to use table as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the predicate information:

```
--------------------------------------
 1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("DIME_MASTER"."SSN")=226550956 
            AND TO_NUMBER("DIME_MASTER"."ACCOUNT_NUMBER")=4425050005218650 
            AND TO_NUMBER("DIME_MASTER"."CIN")=00335093464)
```

The type of your columns is NVARCHAR, but parameters in the query are NUMBERs.
Oracle must cast numbers to strings, but it is sometimes not very smart in casting.

Oracles and fortune-tellers are not always right ;)
These casts prevents the query from using indices.
Rewrite the query using explicit conversion into:

```
Select RELATIONSHIP 
  from DIME_MASTER 
 WHERE CIN=to_char(?) AND SSN=to_char(?) AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER=to_char(?)
```

then run this command:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( user, 'DIME_MASTER' );
```

and run the query and show us a new explain plan.
Would you please do not paste explain plans here, they are unreadable, 
please use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) instead, and paste only links here, thank you.

Look at this simple example, it shows why you need explicit casts:

```
CREATE TABLE "DIME_MASTER" ( 
  "ACCOUNT_NUMBER" NVARCHAR2(16)
);
insert into dime_master
select round( dbms_random.value( 1, 100000 )) from dual
connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
create index dime_master_acc_ix on dime_master( account_number );

explain plan for select * from dime_master
where account_number = 123;

select * from table( dbms_xplan.display );

Plan hash value: 1551952897

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |             |     3 |    54 |    70   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DIME_MASTER |     3 |    54 |    70   (3)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("ACCOUNT_NUMBER")=123)




explain plan for select * from dime_master
where account_number = to_char( 123 );

select * from table( dbms_xplan.display );
Plan hash value: 3367829596

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |                    |     3 |    54 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| DIME_MASTER_ACC_IX |     3 |    54 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("ACCOUNT_NUMBER"=U'123')
```

Comment: sorry late reply, before seeing your reply, I was able to find it same thing that oracle was doing to_char to number & hence was not using required indexes and taking more time to execute queries. I had modified my query something like below:

Comment: Select RELATIONSHIP
      from DIME_MASTER
     WHERE CIN=? AND SSN=? AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER=? and CIN like '?%' and SSN like '?%' and ACCOUNT_NUMBER LIKE '?%'    and it started using index & query is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the cardinality of the columns (Total rows / unique values ) - you can create bitmap indexes on each column. Bitmap indexes are very usefull for `and` / `or` operations.

Rule of thumb says that a bitmap index is useful for cardinality of more then 10%.

```
create bitmap index DIME_MASTER_CIN_BIX on DIME_MASTER (CIN);
```

Comment: How do i use it then in Query?

Comment: i have created 2 bitmap indexes for CIN & SSN  `create bitmap index DIME_MASTER_CIN_BIX on DIME_MASTER (CIN);

create bitmap index DIME_MASTER_SSN_BIX on DIME_MASTER (SSN);` but there is no improvement in performance. Query is still taking 11.3 to 11.5 secs.

Comment: DIME_MASTER STRUCTURE                                          `CREATE
  TABLE "DIME"."DIME_MASTER"
  (
    "ACCOUNT_NUMBER" NVARCHAR2(16),
    "APPLICATION_NUMBER" NVARCHAR2(14),
    "FIRST_NAME" NVARCHAR2(15),
    "LAST_NAME" NVARCHAR2(25),
    "SSN" NVARCHAR2(9),
    "CIN" NVARCHAR2(12),
    "DATE_UPDATED" DATE,
    "BOOK_INDICATOR" NVARCHAR2(1),
    "CARD_NUMBER" NVARCHAR2(16),
    "RELATIONSHIP" NVARCHAR2(1)
  )`

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            |  Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  |
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |              |     1 |    79 |  2365 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL   | DIME_MASTER  |     1 |    79 |  2365 |

 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
--------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("DIME_MASTER"."SSN")=226550956 AND 
              TO_NUMBER("DIME_MASTER"."ACCOUNT_NUMBER")=4425050005218650 AND 
              TO_NUMBER("DIME_MASTER"."CIN")=00335093464)
 
Note: cpu costing is off

Comment: from above explain plan it looks like indexes are not getting used at all and oracle is going for full table scan. I tried using hint as below but still execution plan says full table scan `select  /*+ index(DIME_MASTER (DIME_MASTER_CIN_BIX)) */ * from   DIME_MASTER where CIN=00335093464`